# CMD ocultar texto al escribir

Tags: cmd, batch

forma de encriptar o no mostrar texto al escribir en CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lástimosamente no se puede hacer directamente, se debe recurrir ya sea a un script auxiliar, o bien usar la powershell.

Esta solución emplea la segunda opción, pero desde cmd

`password.bat`

```
powershell -Command $password = read-host "Ingrese password: " -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password) ; ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt 
set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
echo %password%
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduen, tu respuesta es exactamente la que resuelve mi duda.

Comment: No investigué mucho pero también estaría la alternativa de usar ANSI directamente en CMD para hacer esto. Y aparentemente en Windows 10 (con la actualización del aniversario) tiene algunas herramientas para hacer esto. Lo dejo como dato para una futura investigación.